# How to ingest Parquet files residing on AWS S3 into Druid

Tags: parquet, druid

I'm very new to Druid and want to know how we can ingest Parquet files on S3 into Druid?
We get data in CSV format and we standardise it to Parquet format in the Data Lake. This then needs to be loaded into Druid.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to ingest parquet files from S3, I streamed data to a Kinesis topic and used that as a source for Druid.

Comment: Any particular reason for not directly ingesting S3 files to Druid?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `druid-parquet-extensions` in the `druid.extensions.loadList` in the common.runtime.properties file.

After that you can restart the Druid server.

However, only ingesting a parquet file from local source is documented. I couldn't verify loading from S3 as my files were encrypted.

Try adding the above extension and then read from S3 just like you'd ingest a regular file from S3.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Will try it out.

Comment: Have implemented an alternate way of ingesting while waiting for an answer. Will update if I do it in the advised way for sure.

Comment: @Maarab then add your answer so it can help others, or add it in the comments